# Random Number Generator w/ no Repeats Modification?

Tags: javascript, html

So I looked up the JavaScript problem of my last question, and I found a [somewhat] solution to the problem. But I need it to be slightly modified, yet I'm not sure how. Here's what the code does.

```
var nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
var gen_nums = [];

function in_array(array, el) {
   for(var i = 0 ; i < array.length; i++) 
       if(array[i] == el) return true;
   return false;
}

function get_rand(array) {
    var rand = array[Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length)];
    if(!in_array(gen_nums, rand)) {
       gen_nums.push(rand); 
       return rand;
    }
    return get_rand(array);
}

for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    document.write(get_rand(nums));
}
```

This generates a random number with those 12 numbers without any repeat. Yet, I need it to do this for 9 table boxes. Here's my table HTML + the JavaScript code.

## HTML

```
<div id="answers">
  <table class="randomizerAnswers">
    <tr id="answerRowOne">
      <td id="answerBoxOne"></td>
      <td id="answerBoxTwo"></td>
      <td id="answerBoxThree"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="answerRowTwo">
      <td id="answerBoxFour"></td>
      <td id="answerBoxFive"></td>
      <td id="answerBoxSix"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="answerRowThree">
      <td id="answerBoxSeven"></td>
      <td id="answerBoxEight"></td>
      <td id="answerBoxNine"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

## JavaScript

```
function getRandom() {
  var nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
  var gen_nums = [];

  function in_array(array, el) {
    for(var i = 0 ; i < array.length; i++) 
      if(array[i] == el) return true;
    return false;
  }

  function get_rand(array) {
    var rand = array[Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length)];
    if(!in_array(gen_nums, rand)) {
      gen_nums.push(rand); 
      return rand;
    }
    return get_rand(array);
  }

  for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    return (get_rand(nums));
  }
}
function timeOut(){
  /* This can be ignored, as it was a testing function for creating, making, and fixing the randomizer tool, but may change based on creating new tools that need to be troubleshooted. */
  setTimeout (changeRandom, 1);
}
/* This is the function that grabs the innerHTML (what the box says) of the #output1 and changes that number to the word specified. [In example, if the number [randomly] generated was 5, then this function detects that the number was 5 and changes it to Word 5.]  */
function changeRandom()  {
  /* Using the "var x" command, this tells the function that whenever there's an x in the code, it will read it as "document.getElementById('output1').innerHTML", and will grab whatever is inside that #output1 element. */
  var x = document.getElementById('output1').innerHTML
  /* Here's the tutorial for modifying this tool for the possible answers. This tool [by default] has it set to  */
  if(x == 1)  {
    document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = "Word 1";
  } else if(x == 2)  {
    document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = "Word 2";
  } else if(x == 3)  {
    document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = "Word 3";
  } else if(x == 4)  {
    document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = "Word 4" 
  } else if(x == 5) {
    document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = "Word 5"
  }
  else if(x == 6) {
    document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = "Word 6"
  } 
  else if(x == 7) {
    document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = "Word 7"
  }
  else if(x == 8) {
    document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = "Word 8"
  }
  else if(x == 9) {
    document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = "Word 9"
  }
  else if(x == 10) {
    document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = "Word 10"
  }
  /* If the function is broken [by user modifications], it will output "Error :c", which means the user should check their modifications. */
  else  {
    document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = "Error :c"
  }
}
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = getRandom(); changeRandom();})
function getRandomAnswer() {
  var nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
  var gen_nums = [];

  function in_array(array, el) {
    for(var i = 0 ; i < array.length; i++) 
      if(array[i] == el) return true;
    return false;
  }

  function get_rand(array) {
    var rand = array[Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length)];
    if(!in_array(gen_nums, rand)) {
      gen_nums.push(rand); 
      return rand;
    }
    return get_rand(array);
  }

  for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    return(get_rand(nums));
  }
}
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){
document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = getRandom(); changeRandom();})
```

What it would normally do is generate a number like it normally would with the modification so it fits the code & HTML, and then the changeRandom would make it the word. I tried everything, I examined the code, I just couldn't figure it out; as I need to have it do the same thing, but be 1 number for each different box with no repeats. Is this possible? This is mandatory for the project for my class.

Comment: In `getRandom`, you could save the index, `Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length)`, push to `gen_nums` as you are, but also remove from `nums` with `nums.splice(index, 1)`.

Comment: I'm sorry @bozdoz , but I'm not a complete pro at JavaScript, I'm actually quite new. Can you put that in a code? It's rather confusing.

Comment: *"Using the "var x" command, this tells the function that whenever there's an x in the code, it will read it as "document.getElementById('output1').innerHTML", and will grab whatever is inside that #output1 element."* No, the value will be grabbed from the element right away and copied to the `x` variable. Whenever you use `x` after that you get the value stored in the variable, it won't get it from the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could remove the values from `nums` for every iteration in `getRandom`; that way there won't be a duplicate:

```
function getRandom() {
  var nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
  var gen_nums = [];

  function get_rand(array) {
    var i = Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length);
    var rand = array[i];
    gen_nums.push(rand);
    // remove from original array
    nums.splice(i, 1);
  }

  for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    get_rand(nums);
  }
  return gen_nums;
}
```

Also, you had way too many return statements in there.  You don't need to be returning or recursing those functions.

Here's a fiddle of that function : http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/ey0jsy9r/

### Update

To respond to the comment in this answer, you should be able to iterate the elements in the same for loop as the one in which you get a random number:

```
    for (var i = 0, len = nums.length; i < len; i++) {
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * copy.length);
        var rand = copy[ j ];

        // remove from array
        copy.splice(j, 1);

        // add to output
        document.getElementById('output' + (i + 1)).innerHTML = rand;
    }
```

New fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ey0jsy9r/1/

Comment: This isn't what I'm asking. It was working fine, I jsut need it to be able to run 1 number each for 9 boxes, so lets say td box 1 gets 5, td box 2 gets 6, etc

Comment: @DavidVex I was trying to go off the title of the question.  It's hard to tell exactly what you're having trouble with.  How about looping through the HTML elements using the numbers from the for loop to reference them, like `document.getElementById('output' + (i + 1)).innerHTML = rand;`.  See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure if i was clear what you were having trouble with either. Using your code - with the addition , this will use your array and filler in random number in each box. ( bind to click ) - not sure if this is what you were looking for but maybe it can help with a part of it .

```
var nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
var gen_nums = [];

function in_array(array, el) {
   for(var i = 0 ; i < array.length; i++) 
       if(array[i] == el) return true;
   return false;
}

function get_rand(array) {
    var rand = array[Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length)];
    if(!in_array(gen_nums, rand)) {
       gen_nums.push(rand); 
       return rand;
    }
    return get_rand(array);
}

function populateTable(){
    // get the table(s)
    var tables = document.getElementsByClassName('randomizerAnswers'); 
// loop though each table 
    for(i=0; i<tables.length;i++){
        // get all rows for that table 
        var table_rows = tables[i].getElementsByTagName('tr');
        // loop though each row in table and get all the td
        for(j=0; j<table_rows.length;j++){
            var td = table_rows[j].getElementsByTagName('td');
            // no loop though each td 
            for(k=0;k<td.length;k++){
                td[k].innerHTML = get_rand(nums);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

// add your event listener to your button and call 
    populateTable();